# How to add an entry to the hosts file inside a Docker container?

Tags: bash, macos, docker, apache-kafka

I have a Kafka instance running on my local machine (macOS Mojave) and I'm trying to have a Docker container see that.

There are two files in the Java program that will be built as the Docker container:

`docker-entrypoint.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST_DOMAIN="kafka"
HOST_IP=$(awk '/32 host/ { print f } {f=$2}' <<< "$(</proc/net/fib_trie)" | head -n 1)
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
# ...
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh ./
RUN chmod 755 docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN apt-get install -y sudo
CMD ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Now I want to write the following line:

`$HOST_IP\t$HOST_DOMAIN`

to `/etc/hosts` so the Docker container can work with Kafka. How can I do that, considering elevated access is needed to write to that file? I have tried these:

1- Changing `CMD ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]` to `CMD ["sudo", "./docker-entrypoint.sh"]`

2- Using `sudo tee`

3- Using `su root;tee ...`

4- Running `echo "%<user> ALL=(ALL) ALL" | tee -a /etc/sudoers > /dev/null`, so I can then `tee ...` without `sudo`.

1, 2, and 3 lead to the following error:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

I don't understand this error. A search for it had solutions for when one is `ssh`ing to run a command, but here there is no `ssh`.

To do 4, I already need to be `sudo`, correct?

So, how can I achieve what I'm looking to do?

Comment: I would say `sudo` is asking for a password, but it's being executed in a non-interactive mode (so there's no TTY), so it fails. You can for example configure the user so it can use `sudo` without a password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dockerfile commands typically run as root unless you've changed the user account, so you should not need sudo.

---

**You don't need to edit any hosts file**

You can use `host.docker.internal` to reach the host from the container

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/

Otherwise, just run Kafka in a container if you want to setup things locally

Comment: When I do `echo $USER` I get `appdata` back. Also when I leave out `sudo` I get `tee: Permission denied`.

Comment: Updated my answer to be more clear. Try `USER root` before you need something that requires elevated privileges. In any case, why do you really need to tee anything? You seem to have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)